# Функция должна решать квадратное уравнение вида ax^2 +bx + c = 0. возвращать в виде массива корни уравнения x1, x2. PHP функции

Tags: php

Функция решающая квадратное уравнение.

Описание

Функция должна решать квадратное уравнение вида ax^2 +bx + c = 0.

Функция должна принимать в качестве параметров значения a, b, c и возвращать в виде массива корни уравнения x1, x2. Пример возвращаемого массива: ['x1' => 5, ‘x2’ => 9]. Один или оба элемента могут содержать значение NULL в случае если уравнение имеет только один корень или, соответственно, не имеет решений вовсе.

```
<?php

function sqr($num1, $num2, $num3) {

$d = (pow($num2, 2)) - (4 * ($num1 * $num3));
if ($d > 0) {
    $x1 = -($num2 + sqrt($d)/(2 * $num1));
    $x2 = -($num2 - sqrt($d)/(2 * $num1));
    echo "x1 = $x1 <br> x2 = $x2";
}
elseif ($d == 0) {
    $x1 = $x2 = -($num2/(2 * $num1));
    echo "равны: $x1";
}
elseif ($d < 0) {
    echo 'Нет корня';
}

}

sqr(-1, -2, 15);

?>
```

Выдаёт неправильные значения (например сейчас выдало -6 и 3)

Comment: 1. Скобок у вас избыточно и неправильно, 2. Из функции нужно возвращать массив, а не выводить результат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка заключается в этой строке:

```
$x1 = -($num2 + sqrt($d)/(2 * $num1));
$x2 = -($num2 - sqrt($d)/(2 * $num1));
```

Замените на:

```
$x1 = (-$num2 + sqrt($d))/(2 * $num1);
$x2 = (-$num2 - sqrt($d))/(2 * $num1);
```

Вот готовый код:

```php
<?php

function sqr($num1, $num2, $num3) {

$d = (pow($num2, 2)) - (4 * ($num1 * $num3));
if ($d > 0) {
    $x1 = (-$num2 + sqrt($d))/(2 * $num1);
    $x2 = (-$num2 - sqrt($d))/(2 * $num1);
    echo "x1 = $x1 <br> x2 = $x2";
}
elseif ($d == 0) {
    $x1 = $x2 = -$num2/(2 * $num1);
    echo "равны: $x1";
}
elseif ($d < 0) {
    echo 'Нет корня';
}

}

sqr(-1, -2, 15);

?>
```

И вот с возвратом массива:

```php
<?php

function sqr($num1, $num2, $num3) {

$d = (pow($num2, 2)) - (4 * ($num1 * $num3));
if ($d > 0) {
    $x1 = (-$num2 + sqrt($d))/(2 * $num1);
    $x2 = (-$num2 - sqrt($d))/(2 * $num1);
    return [$x1, $x2];
}
elseif ($d == 0) {
    $x1 = $x2 = -$num2/(2 * $num1);
    return [$x1, $x2];
}
elseif ($d < 0) {
    return [];
}

}

sqr(-1, -2, 15);

?>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Почему то ничего не выводит

Comment: если нужен именно вывод (например при вставке в html файле и парсинга файла перед отправкой как вероятно вы делаете) то добавьте в конце этот код $result = sqr(-1, -2, 15);
if ($result)
{
 echo "Корни:";
 foreach ($result as $current) {
  echo " ", $current;
 }
}
else
{
 echo "Нету решения";
}